# Generating a subnet mask from a subnet and address prefix length

Tags: c, subnet

I have a file that store some subnet info on a line like this:

```
123.123.0.0/16 123.123.123.123
```

The first part is the subnet and the address prefix length, followed by the ip address of the node a packet going that way should go to.

I am trying to determine if a given IP is part of the subnet, I understand how this process is supposed to work for the most part. But I am not sure how to go about generating a subnet-mask from the info above.

The options I've considered:

I've found a number of tables online for address prefix lengths from 1-32, so I could throw one of those into a switch statement and call it a day, but this seems gross.

The address prefix length gives me the number of '1's in the mask starting from the left. Therefore, 32 - Address Prefix Length gives the number of '0's from the right. I could add powers of 2 from 2^address prefix length to 2^32 and use the result as the subnet mask. I am a little worried about this idea though, I have a feeling a regular int would overflow if I tried to do that, so I should use a uint32_t maybe? I'm not sure.

Would option 2 work? Should I just go for option 1? Is there a better way?

I am doing this in C.

Answer (score 2):

You can form a mask of all ones with `~0`.  You'll need to shift that left by `32-n` bits, to leave `n` low-order bits empty:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t subnet_mask(int prefix_len)
{
    return prefix_len ? ~0 << (32 - prefix_len) : 0;
}

/* Unit tests */
int main()
{
    return 0xFFFFFF00u != subnet_mask(24)
        +  0x00000000u != subnet_mask(0)
        +  0xFFFFFFFFu != subnet_mask(32);
}
```

The special case (found by the unit tests) is easily missed - `uint32` shifted left 32 bits is treated as not shifted at all.  Watch out for the extreme cases!

Answer (score 0):

This will work for `prefix` in the range 1 to 32:`0xFFFFFFFFU & -(1U << (32 - prefix))`

Answer (score 0):

The following (untested) macro should work for values 0 thru 31.  It produces a mask that can be ANDed with an IPv4 address to produce the subnet part of the address.  n is the # of bits in the subnet portion of the IPv4 address.

```
#define SUBNET_MASK(n) ((1u << (n)) - 1)
```

The following (also untested macro) produces the network address portion of the subnet.  n is the # of bits in the subnet portion of the IPv4 address.

```
#define NETWORK_MASK(n) (~SUBNET_MASK(n))
```